# select xpath of data in a tag using lxml

Tags: python, xpath, screen-scraping, lxml

I am trying to select the "**(6)**" in the tag below:

```
<a class="itemRating" href="http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductReview.aspx?Item=N82E16834200347" title="Rating + 4">
<span class="eggs r4">&nbsp;</span>
(6)
</a>
```

The xpath, which I will call review, is in the () below:

```
review = site.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/table/tr/td[2]/div/div[8]/div/div/div/a[3]
```

When I try printing `review[0]`.text, it prints '`None'` instead of the `(6)`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

`(6)` is in the tail of `<span>` element:

```
>>> a[0].tail
'\n(6)\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
review[0].text_content().strip()
```

or

```
review[0].xpath('string()').strip()
```

And I'd write your xpath as:

```
review = site.xpath('//a[@class="itemRating"]')
```